# How to Fix open for write P4 ERROR?

Tags: linux, perforce

I am having difficulty getting rid if the following error:

> bash-3.00$ p4 login
>
> Enter password:
>
> Fatal client error; disconnecting!
>
> open for write: /home/myuserid/tmp.17236.3: No such file or directory

The file does not exist nor do I know why it ever did.

How can I clear this?

Thanks

Comment: type 'p4 set', 'set | grep P4', and 'p4 -V' and paste the output into your question. If you have 'P4CONFIG' set, also paste the output of 'cat $P4CONFIG'

Comment: set | grep P4 only prints P4CLIENT, P4PASSWD and P4PORT which I would rather not put up here.

cat $P4CONFIG is not set.

p4 -V produces:

Perforce - The Fast Software Configuration Management System.
Copyright 1995-2008 Perforce Software.  All rights reserved.
Rev. P4/LINUX26X86/2008.2/179173 (2008/12/05).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a permission issue on my home directory.

Once the home directory was created correctly the issue was resolved

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of environment variables that might be at play.   They control the temp location that Perforce uses for intermediate files, and also the location of the tickets file that contains the login tickets.  As Bryan mentioned you should run 'p4 set' and look at your Perforce-related environment.

Comment: set | grep P4 only prints P4CLIENT, P4PASSWD and P4PORT which I would rather not put up here. cat $P4CONFIG is not set. p4 -V produces: Perforce - The Fast Software Configuration Management System. Copyright 1995-2008 Perforce Software. All rights reserved. Rev. P4/LINUX26X86/2008.2/179173 (2008/12/05).

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click *cmd.exe*
2. "Run as Administrator"
3. try your command again